# TopComponent causing project not to build in Netbeans 12.6, reoccurring error : Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required

Tags: java, dependencies, maven-3, netbeans-12

I have a project (written in Java using the Netbeans Platform 12.6), which is composed by several Tabs (all of them are created subclassing the TopComponent class).
The project is neither cleaning nor building and I keep getting this error:

```
'COMPILATION ERROR : 
 <hr>
com//ProgramTopComponent.java:[40,13] error: 
Could not generate files: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:\\Program-module\\program\module\Bundle.properties (Access is denied)
<hr>

'BUILD FAILURE
<hr>
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile 
(default-compile) on project Program-module: 
Compilation failure:
com//program/module/ProgramTopComponent.java:[40,13] 
error: Could not generate files:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\\\Program\Program-module\\\\\program\module\Bundle.properties (Access is denied)
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

 For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following        articles:
cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException'
```

In Command Prompt I get:

---

BUILD FAILURE

---

Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one
of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to central
(//repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file:
/repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/
maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom.
**Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.**

```
 To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 
 For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
 please read the following articles:
 cwiki.apache.org//confluence//display//MAVEN//PluginResolutionException
```

With the -X trace enabled when cleaning in CMD

---

BUILD FAILURE

---

Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1:
**Could not transfer artifact:**
**Failed to read artifact descriptor for:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1**
...
**Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1**
...
**Failed to transfer file:
"repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/
2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom.
Return code is:
501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.**

TLDR: it's giving me the ERROR 501 = ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. but I've Ctrl-F'ed the entire file project and I can't find any instance where http is called where it should be https.

What is causing this hang?

I have gone through all of the .pom files, settings files, manifest files and .config files associated with this program to make sure that all http declarations are https. Additionally, I have wiped out generated build files and built again. I have manually gone and pulled the associated dependencies from the central Maven repository.

I'm really hoping I'm just doing something terribly stupid and overlooking a simple thing.
Has anyone else run into this?

settings.xml has already been updated to point to the updated repository

I have already explicitly declared the repository in my .pom file

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access a repository without https ... `ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.`.. furthermore you are using extremely old plugin versions also which version of Maven do you use? I assume you are using an old version... which can be the reason for using http instead of https...

Comment: I'm using Maven3. I have updated all the references to https. I have explicitly declared the maven repository: "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/" in the settings and all places available in the .pom file.                        I'm not sure where else I should be updating

Comment: [Which version of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)?? please post that configuration of the`settings.xml` why in the pom file? Only belongs into `settings.xml` and the output looks like you did something wrong in `settings.xml` file...Also Netbeans version 12 sounds very old...